# Editing profile...

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, mobile-web, user-profile

I have edited my profile some 20 days ago.  But I don't see any option for editing my profile.  Can I not edit my profile nowafter?  Do I have to wait for some more days?

Comment: On your [user page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/354073/newton) when you are logged in there are three tabs at the top: "Profile" "Activity" "Edit profile&settings" you need to select the last. You cannot edit your display name frequently (30 days), you should be able to change other aspects though.

Comment: @quid, I am using Mobile.. Chrome of Android.. So, I couldn't view the last tab you told. how do I view that

Comment: Sorry, I have not much idea about mobile. Do you use the app or just view it in a  browser on a mobile device? Either way  as an immediate workaround for this not too frequent task you could open the page in the browser of your modbile device (not the app) and change to full site view. There is a link in the footer "full site" you can then change bakc to the mobile view in the analogous way.